# Loop through all cells with white fill and change them to no fill

Tags: excel, vba

I have a huge spreadsheet. I want to loop through all cells and change the white fill to no fill. This code either takes too long or crashes my computer so I cannot tell if it actually works. Does anyone see anything wrong with it?

```
Sub Remove_White_Cells()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook
        For Each cell In Worksheets
            If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
                cell.Interior.Color = xlNone
            End If
        Next cell
    Next ws


End Sub
```

Comment: `For Each cell In Worksheets.UsedRange`

Comment: Since you looping through each worksheet, using the variable `ws`, you should be using `For Each cell in ws.UsedRange`

Comment: Also, stopping automatic recalculation can speed things up a bit. Add this to the start of your code:  `Dim SaveCalcState  SaveCalcState = Application.Calculation  Application.Calculation = XlManual`  And this to the end:  `Application.Calculation = SaveCalcState`

Comment: You can't iterate through cells with an `ActiveSheet` ,  which is why you are likely getting the error `Object doesn't support this property or method`  Basically, when you tell VBA to iterate through `ActiveSheet` it doesn't automatically know that you are talking about cells.  That is why you have to change the object to a `UsedRange` which is a `range` type.  Then VBA knows you want to iterate through cells.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.usedrange

Comment: There are over 17 Billion cells in a worksheet. You absolutely don't want to process them all. That's what UsedRange avoids. :-)

Comment: "This code either takes too long or crashes my computer so I cannot tell if it actually works". That code, if it works, needs to loop through every cell in every worksheet. And this is 16384 columns * 1048576 rows per worksheet. Quite a lot of electricity waste...

Comment: So apparently ```UsedRange``` did not work. I still have white cells. The reason I want to do this is because I inherited a financial model with a few white cells filled in rows for all columns, making the spreadsheet ridiculously large. What constitutes a ```used cell```?

Comment: Untested, but maybe you could use the [Inquire Add-In](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-you-can-do-with-spreadsheet-inquire-ebaf3d62-2af5-4cb1-af7d-e958cc5fad42)? Not sure if it would remove this formatting or not, but maybe worth a shot. Inquire is pre-installed since Excel 2013.

Comment: Use Find and Replace, simply initiate a FindFormat and ReplaceFormat. This removes the need for any cell iteration

Answer (score 0):

First of all, code that loops through every cell in every worksheet is extremely inefficient. For this reason I would use `.UsedRange` to limit it to the used cells.

The result is the following:

```
Sub Remove_White_Cells()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim cell As Range
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 'Worksheet iterator
    For Each cell In ws.UsedRange.Cells 'Select only used cells
        If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
            cell.Interior.Color = xlNone
        End If
    Next cell
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```